# appcelerator Android get carrier name?

Tags: android, appcelerator

i have project done with `Appcelerator` Titanium , i've created module to get carrier name in IOS , i am looking for Android module or method to provide carrier name , so far i've found 2 modules both are too old is not compatible with `appcelerator` sdk 6.0.4.GA , any advice how to get carrier name in android appcelerator ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the modules you've found but my module: https://github.com/m1ga/com.miga.gsm is compiled for SDK 6+ and returns the `operatorname`.